# Auto Import in VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am a new user of VSCode with Angular4. Auto Import extension is installed and working with modules within my project but Intellisense is not suggesting or completing imports for @angular and other node_modules. The Glob setting is '**/*.{ts,tsx}'. Is there any other setting that is required?

Environment: Node: 8.4.0, VSCode: 1.16.1 @angular: 4.4.3, OSX: 10.12.6

Comment: Try using typescript hero.its much better and works with external(3rd party) modules also

Comment: Thanks Karan, that's working for me; much appreciated.

Comment: @meljturner I am the author of Auto Import - It was just a side project that got quite popular - I agree with Karan Garg - Typescript hero is a much better choice now

Comment: Typescript hero, is very slow when enable AutoSave mode, and not suggest any import in Angular5